# How to solve an linear system with b variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, education

I have the following:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 \\ 3 & -5\end{bmatrix};
b = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}
$$

and I'm thinking how to analyse the Ax = b system. As I saw I could introduce the missing variables as so:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 3 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}
x = \begin{bmatrix} \xi \\ \eta \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}
b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then I would be able to analyze the system starting with something like so:

$$
(i) \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 0 &| &0 \\ 3 & -5 & 0 &| &0\\ 0 & 0 & -1&| &0\end{bmatrix}
$$

However it doesn't seems so good, since as I deduce I would find something like:

$$
\beta = -1 \\ \xi = 0 \\ \eta = 0
$$

How can I solve that?

Comment: When introducing the missing variable $\beta$ you also added an extra row to the matrix equation, which restricted $\beta$ to satisfy $-\beta = 0$.

Comment: Is there a problem related to just directly solving the first form of the equation? Just multiply and add the rows ...

Comment: You probably mean

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&0\\3&-5&-1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\xi\\\eta\\\beta\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @MattiP. Got it! I thought about separating that way because I wanted the independent values (instead of something like $\beta  = 2\xi$), I don't know if that makes sense, by seeing the answers I could say I doesn't.

Comment: $\det A\ne0$. What does this tell you about the solutions to $Ax=b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve the $2 \times 2$ system, treating $\beta$ as a constant. That will give you $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to find the $x$, $y$ and $\beta$ independent values?

Comment: @FelipeAugusto: I'm not sure what you mean by that. For each value of $\beta$ you get values for $x$ and $y$. (Or for each value of $x$ you get values for $y$ and $\beta$. Etc.)

Comment: I mean variables values not related to other variables values, I already saw some examples of using identity matrix to find each variable, I don't know if that makes sense though.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're looking for. If you view your equations as a system for the three unknowns $(x,y,\beta)$, then there are infinitely many solutions, since for **every** given value of $\beta$, you can find corresponding values of $x$ and $y$ such that the triple $(x,y,\beta)$ satisfies the equations.

Comment: Oh, thank you! that answers my question, I don't have an unique solution, but infinitely many solutions! I think what I was looking for was the possible unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & -5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x  \\ y \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$ is equivalent to the two equations $x+ 2y= 0$, $3x- 5y= \beta$.  Subtract 3 times the first equation from the second:  $-11y= \beta$ so $y= -\frac{\beta}{11}$.  Then $x= -2y= -\frac{2\beta}{11}$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to find the $x$, $y$ and $\beta$ independent values?

Comment: With two equations you can solve for any two of the unknowns in terms of the third.  You cannot solve for specific values of all three.